# fgets cannot capture output from tty device

Tags: c, pipe, fgets

I am trying to get the RSSI value from a Option modem installed as ttyHS4 (control) and ttyHS5 (data) on a Linux board. Expected result shows up on console but the fgets just does not capture any console output data.

```
if ((f=popen("echo -e \"AT+CSQ\r\n\">dev\ttyHS4","r"))==NULL){  
perror("popen");  
exit(1);  
}  

while (fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),f){  
printf(":%s:\n",buff);  
}
```

I tested with "echo \"TEST\"" in the popen command and code above was able to print out the ":TEST:" string. With the ttyHS4 output, I only can get a few output on the console but the fgets + fprintf does not get any data to work on.

Please advise where I could have faulted.

Comment: And prepend a `/` to the path

Comment: You mean the \r\n\ for the AT+CSQ? Remember that I was able to get the RSSI and BER value,i.e. +CSQ: 16,99. Problem its only on the Linux console and not via the fgets in the C program. Anyway - I tried it, removed the \r - this time, totally no result.

Comment: Yes - there is a typo - its echo -e "AT+CSQ\r\n">/dev/ttyHS4. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `popen()` to create a file descriptor that channels to your main program the standard output of this command:

```
echo -e ... >/dev/ttyHS4
```

You *do* realize that this command sends nothing to that file descriptor, right? `popen()` opens a shell - normally `/bin/sh` - which *then* executes that command. Due to the redirection to `/dev/ttyHS4`, the `echo` command does not send its standard output to the same file descriptor as its parent shell, which leads to nothing being written to `f` - and even if that was not the issue, `echo` would never read back the modem response to you..

But why are you even using `popen()` and `echo`, instead of just opening `/dev/ttyHS4` read/write and using `read()` and `write()` on the resulting file descriptor directly?

Comment: Thanks. A linux newbie mistep, since I could get ttyHS4 to print back to the console after echo'ing the AT command to it, I expected that fgets would be able to capture the response from the ttyHS4. I am now using write() and read() and in string parsing hell phase ... Thank you for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unusual to have a tab character in a path.  You probably meant to do:

```
popen("echo \"AT+CSQ\">/dev/ttyHS4","r")
```

Comment: Example was from Option Wireless driver manual - 
  
#echo –e “<AT command>\r\n” > /dev/ttyHSx

Comment: I just wonder why I can get the right results sent to the console when I execute my C program with the code, but the fgets does not capture anything at all. Thanks.